# Adding a Form to a WebForm? .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, user-controls, webforms

I have a WebForm in my app and when I add a second `<form></form>` it crashes the script because I'm only allowed one Form.

What is the best way to include a 2nd form on the script?

Should I be calling it with a UserControl instead?

Many thanks for any guidance.

Comment: You you need to add the second form tag? One form tag must exists per page.

Comment: Might be useful to add to your question what exactly you are trying to achieve with your second `<form>`. You may be trying to do things in a "non-WebForms-ish" way, and it might be a lot easier to take a different approach, rather than trying to figure out how to make your second form work.

Comment: Good call. It's a very basic 'Subscribe' form to allow users to submit name and email. It was initially in my 'SiteMaster' file, but I now think it's easier to have it in it's own Subscribe.aspx page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the second form to be a client side form (no `runat="server"` attribute), simply place it outside the server side form.

If you want two server side forms, this is not possible - one of the limitations of ASP.NET webforms.

Comment: Hi Oded :) Thanks for this. I will give it a try without `runat="server"` and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that... ASP.NET says there can't be 2 or more forms with runat = server... Just make you new form NOT runat = server.. Plain simple HTML form

Comment: Hi Ankur. Thanks for this advice. I will give it a try without `runat="server"` and see how I fair.